# Avoid loss of translation when overwriting a block

Tags: php, magento

If I rewrite a block and developer mode is active, the standard translation is not displayed any more. How can I make Magento to fall back to the original translation of the module.

This is related to [Magento: Avoid loss of translations when rewriting controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882584/magento-avoid-loss-of-translations-when-rewriting-controllers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to overwrite the module name in the block which is used to determine which translations should be used:

```
class Acme_GreatModule_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation
{
    /**
     * Set the original module name to avoid breaking translations
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setModuleName('Mage_Customer');
    }     
...
```

Comment: Please mark your question as the answer, works like a charm (also with `_construct()` method).